# Issue with .ConfigureKestrel() method in .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, kestrel

I'm trying to create a very simple API with .net Core, and am exploring Kestrel. I am following the directions on this MS tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2

However, when I try to call the ConfigureKestrel method, Visual Studio tells me that "IWebHostBuilder does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureKestrel()' and no accessible extension method for ConfigureKestrel accepting a first argument of the type 'IWebHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I can't find any info on this, and I'm fairly sure I'm using the right libraries. Any help would be greatly appreciated - code is included:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
        {
            // Error with ConfigureKestrel method above
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty sure an extension method from a namespace you do not import.

Comment: It's probably Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting or Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel

Comment: Even while using both of those namespaces it still doesn't seem to resolve the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a sample application from scratch and this compiles:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureKestrel((a, b) => { });
    }
}
```

Can you check if this example works for you?

Please also check that you have the latest version of .Net Core, perhaps it was changed? The documentation is 2.2

Comment: My issue is that I was running 2.1 - thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Found the VS2017 ASP.NET Core Web Application -> API running 2.1 does not have the ConfigureKestrel. However you can pass a KestrelServerOptions Action into UseKestrel instead which may give you the control your after. It overrides the settings from CreateDefaultBuilder.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>().UseKestrel(options => options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback,60000));
```

Incidentally I just found if you start with a plain .NetCore console app, then add...

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
```

This gives you a (fairly minimalist) project running AspNetCore 2.2 instead of 2.1

Comment: I'm kind of curious now... if you used the KestrelServerOptions Action with 2.2 would it win or would the values  in the ConfigureKestrel Method win?